# How to debug Emacs to find out why Emacs doesn't open external browser?

Tags: spacemacs, web-browser

In Emacs (27.1) on the orgmode when I RET on HTTP link, Emacs doesn't open it on any browser (chromium, firefox, ...).

I've set these variable in my spacemacs user config:

```
  (setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-browser
        browse-url-generic-program "chromium-browser")

  (setq org-return-follows-link t)
```

I tried this function, but it didn't work for me:

```
(browse-url "http://www.google.com")
```

How can I debug Emacs to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Did you check the *Messages* buffer?

Comment: Yep, there is no corresponding message there.

Comment: You can look at the sources for `browse-url`, You can also instrument `browse-url` with [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html#Debugging) and step through it. IIUC, this is  independent of Org mode, so the `org-mode` tag should be deleted - correct?

Comment: Is the program `chromium-browser` in your `PATH`? (Dunno whether that's necessary; just a thought.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found that the call-process doesn't work due to
the corrupted .spacemacs.env file. after deletion of this file, it works properly.

Comment: Did you find out which part of the .spacemacs.env file specifically interfered here?